# Acceder a carpetas compartidas en Python

Tags: python-3.x

En un entorno Workgroup de Windows, necesito acceder con Python a carpetas compartidas en otras estaciones para hacer diversas operaciones de archivo (verificar, copiar, borrar, etc.)
Debo conectarme mediante usuario y contraseña; y desconectarme luego de finalizado el proceso.
Algo similar al **NET USE** que ya trae Windows.
¿Alguien me puede indicar como hacerlo desde Python?

Comment: No lo he hecho nunca, pero en principio puedes simplemente  usar `NET USE` mediante un subproceso ([subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html)) y luego usar los métodos normales de Python para trabajar con ficheros y archivos.